# Flex in grand(grand)children of row layout

Tags: angularjs, css, flexbox, angular-material

I want to use the flex "system" to obtain something that looks
like the image below, but I have some generated directives between my layout div and the flex ones:

[image]

```
<div id="i-can-control-this-div" layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <div id="uncontrolled-div-generated-by-vendor-directive">
    <div id="another-generated-div">
      <div id="maybe-the-last-one">
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="66">[flex=66]</div>
        </div>
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="33">
            <div style="height:100px">[flex=33]</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="66">[flex=66]</div>
        </div>
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
        </div>
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
        </div>
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
        </div>
        <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
          <div flex="33">[flex=33]</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me something that look like the first section on this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Nephidream/pen/KzxLEr). I guess I could JQuery the style out of those divs but isn't there a cleaner way ?

Comment: why would you use that much deep level of container elements ?

Comment: I personally don't want to but a vendor directive I use generates this kind of depth between my "i-can-control-this-div" and the "flex=*" divs

Comment: Is this will work ? http://codepen.io/next1/pen/xVyPGw  `flex` should be given to container's immediate successor and all its siblings  only.

Comment: It will work yes, but i would have to use JQuery to add classes "flex-*" to direct parent and "layout-row layout-wrap flex" to the grand-parent and "layout-row flex" to 'older' divs. I think it's a good solution yes, I was just hoping that I could avoid to use JQuery to modify generated divs. Don't hesitate to post your answer so that I can validate it (I will just wait a bit to see if another solution purely based on CSS could be proposed)

Comment: Playing a bit with your fork, I see that we can simplify and avoid to modify anything older that the grandparent http://codepen.io/Nephidream/pen/YqJERe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `flex` attribute so that it will contain all the avaliable width.

```
<div id="i-can-control-this-div">
<div id="uncontrolled-div-generated-by-vendor-directive">
  <div id="another-generated-div">
    <div layout="row" flex layout-wrap id="maybe-the-last-one">
      <div flex="66" id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-fl">
        <div>[flex=66]</div>
      </div>
      <div id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex" flex="33">
        <div>
          <div style="height:100px">[flex=33]</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div flex="33" id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
        <div >[flex=33]</div>
      </div>
       <div flex="66" id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
        <div>[flex=66]</div>
      </div>
      <div flex="33" id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
        <div >[flex=33]</div>
      </div>
      <div flex="33" id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
        <div >[flex=33]</div>
      </div>
      <div flex="33"id="uncontrollable-div-arround-each-flex">
        <div >[flex=33]</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

working example.
 http://codepen.io/next1/pen/xVyPGw